# trouble formatting double in my getter method

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

my code:

```
private double retailPrice = 699;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

public double getRetailPrice()
{
  return df.format(retailPrice);
}
```

I am trying to format this for a HW assignment. It's not really required, but I wanted to try this as a learning experience.  The method should return a double, but when I try to use decimal formatter, it gives an error:

> string cannot be converted into a double

but it's not a string...right?

Basically this ends up as part of a StringBuilder object that is written to a csv file, so it needs to be formatted before it is appended to the StringBuilder.

Comment: Because format returns a string but your method says it returns a double. Your must make up your mind. Generally, try to separate data from its presentation

Comment: `df.format()` return `String` and you required a double.

Comment: A `double` is a 64-bit binary representation of a floating point value; it does not have a set number of digits or comma separators (that is a `String`).

Answer (score 1):

Do this

`public String getRetailPrice()
{
    return df.format(retailPrice);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two things.

A double number is just that: a number. It does not know about formatting. Formatting is when you turn numbers into strings.

Those are two different things, and there is simply no point in wanting to format a double value whilst keeping it a double. Your code is pointless, plain and simple.

Solution: either have the getter return the double value as it is. Or change its return type to string. And maybe rename it to "getPriceAsFormattedString" for example.

Answer (score 0):

format method return type is String, so you have to parse again formatted value into double. like below

```
public double getRetailPrice() {
    return Double.valueOf(df.format(retailPrice));
}
```